# ini file for cloudformation parameter file

Tags: configuration, aws-cloudformation, boto3

We're gluing together cloud formation template .yaml files with boto3.  My strong inclination is to use the .ini format for parameter and tag files because

1. .ini format is easier to read than either YAML or json
2. the python 'configparser' library  supports a 'default' section
   which will reduce typing a lot.

Two possible disadvantages to this approach are:

1. native .ini doesn't support lists
2. We might want to feed the parameter files to the aws cli

There are a bunch of ways to extend configparser, the standard python library for handling ini files to handle lists.

I don't **think** we will want or need to feed yaml to the aws cli and converting ini to YAML doesn't seem hard.

What disadvantage of ini am I missing ?

For comparison same file in ini / yaml / json

```
; ini
[default]
  KeyPairName  = MyKey
  InstanceType = m1.micro

# YAML
---
- ParameterKey: KeyPairName
  ParameterValue: MyKey
- ParameterKey: InstanceType
  ParameterValue: m1.micro

json:
    [
  {
    "ParameterKey": "KeyPairName",
    "ParameterValue": "MyKey"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "InstanceType",
    "ParameterValue": "m1.micro"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the problem of .ini not handling list with parameters of type [CommaDelimitedList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html). Considering you only want to use the .ini for parameters and tags, I don't foresee issues of doing this.